# Why this javascript program is not working even whole is correct?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

*Q: The Question Is code a function which will be able to take a word and locate the position of a chosen letter in that given word.*

```
function letterFinder(word,match){
   for(let i=0; i==word.length; i++){
      if(word[i]==match){
        console.log('Found the', match, 'at', i);
      }
      else{
        console.log('---No match found at',i);
      }
   }
}
word="test";
letter="t";
letterFinder(word,letter)
```

My Output look like this:

```
 Found the t at 0
 ---No match found at 1
 ---No match found at 2
 Found the t at 3
```

Comment: I don't get the output in terminal of Mac I am getting blank.

Comment: Your for loop condition is wrong. What it should be is for(let i=0; i<word.length;++i), not i == word.length.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in the given code lies within the for loop condition. The loop will never execute because the condition i == word.length is not met initially. The loop should run as long as i is less than word.length, not when it is equal to it.

To correct the code, you should change the for loop condition from i == word.length to i < word.length

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Your for loop is wrong. Correct it as :**

```
for(let i=0; i < word.length; i++) { }
```

```js
function letterFinder(word,match){
   for(let i=0; i < word.length; i++){
      if(word[i]==match){
        console.log('Found the', match, 'at', i);
      }
      else{
        console.log('---No match found at',i);
      }
   }
}
word="test";
letter="t";
console.log(letterFinder(word,letter))
```